# The Admob banner shows only in my own cellphone

Tags: android, admob

I have integrated my application with the admob, but the banner shows only in my own cellphone, anybody else can't see it.

The internet is working fine, I tested it in several cellphones, but the banner only shows in my own.

Its like it was restricted to my google account.

The adUnitId is correct, I already double checked it, although it doesn't seem to be the problem anyway.

I also checked the permissions in others cellphones. The Internet access is allowed, receiving data from the Internet and see the network status is allowed as well.

Am I missing any step in the integration?

Comment: maybe you forgot .addTestDevice("AC98C820A50B4AD8A2106EDE96FB87D4") as your own phones ID to test it and did not make a getID function for others to generate the ads?

Comment: A did not set an addTestDevice, as I am a beginner in this integration I don't even knew about its existence. What I can say is that it also works in the emulators, when I am testing, but not in any device but my own. Considering that, I dont think it is restricted by phone Id :/

Comment: can you also check your admob account. If you have clicked your own ads they might have limited your account or something. Hope it is fine tho.

Comment: In my admob account everything seems ok. I didn't click in the ads, however I opened my own app, and the adds showed up, so, there was prints, I hope there is no problem with that. I assuming I am allowed to install my own app.

Comment: the most annoying thing is that the admob doesn't provide any support channel, not even an email, who I could contact to explain the problem. Big fail!